# Strange triangle artifacts on bevelling but no rounding

Tags: bevel

I get strange triangle artifacts on bevelling but no rounding of edges. Why and how can I overcome this?

[image]

Comment: Try to select all vertexes and press M -> by distance.

Comment: Is this "Merge by distance"? If yes - I did this. 0 vertices were merged. And I still have the same artifacts...

Comment: in this case, can you share the file?